# How to subdivide the space inside a small multiple

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I need to create small multiples (like the one shown in the picture) using ggplot2 where each circle occupies 70% of the total size of it's  own small multiple and the remaining 30% is empty space.
I know the center and the radius of the circle.

**Question: Is it possible to do this, and if so, how?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Area of ​​a circle = C = π * r²

Area of your square = S = width * length = side²

So just calculate C,  so you can calculate how big S must be to fullfill your criteria. When you know S you know the side, which translates to how you have to set the axis limits for x and y.